# round a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'dayData' and I am trying to round a zero decimal places one of the columns (the column is called 'trace')

I have tried using the following but with no success:

```
dayData["trace"] = dayData["trace"].round(0)
```

I get the exception:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'rint'
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? What version of pandas are you using? I can't replicate this on pandas 0.18.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `import numpy as np`, do

```
dayData["trace"] = dayData["trace"].apply(np.round)
```

Comment: But I concur with Andy Haiden: it works for me in Pandas 0.18.1